# MYSQL Multi-Table Update Is Extremely Slow

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a multi-table update in MYSQL (Amazon RDS) and it is extremely slow.

**What I am trying to do?**

Remove all duplicate rows based on a 1 hour time frame.

Below I created a temp table to identify the duplicate rows in the table. This query runs in 2 seconds.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpIds (id int primary key);
INSERT into tmpIds
SELECT distinct
    d.id
FROM api d INNER JOIN api orig
    on d.domain_id = orig.domain_id and d.user_id = orig.user_id
WHERE
    orig.created_at < d.created_at
    AND d.created_at <= DATE_ADD(orig.created_at, Interval 1 hour)
    AND d.type = 'api/check-end'
    AND d.created_at >= '2016-08-01';

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED ;
```

The problem is the UPDATE query it takes way to long to run on the production server. It also locks the api table.

```
SET @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 1;

UPDATE
    api
SET
    deleted_at = now()
WHERE type = 'api/check-end' AND created_at >= '2016-08-01' 
    AND id IN (SELECT id FROM tmpIds);

SET @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 0;
```

I also tried this version:

```
SET @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 1;

UPDATE
    api a,
    tmpIds ti
SET
     a.deleted_at = now()
WHERE
    type = 'api/check-end'  AND created_at >= '2016-08-01' AND a.domain_id < 10 AND a.id = ti.id;

SET @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 0;
```

**STATS**

- Temp Table: 32,000 rows
- api table: total - 250,000 rows, after where clause (type, created_at)
  200,000 rows.
- The api table has costly triggers, this is why I turned them
  off.
- Sample run for 1000 updates 6 minutes.
- There is an index on the api table primary key

Comment: Show the explain.One thing you could do is replace the subquery with a JOIN but the problem might be that temp table cant be indexed,you might be better of with a real table which you can truncate as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following statement:

```
SET @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 1;
```

Was not disabling the triggers. I had to delete the UPDATE trigger on the api table and the UPDATE ran in 1.3 seconds.

Any help on the best way to disable triggers while running a query?

Comment: If you don't need the trigger, maybe drop it all together and use event scheduler to create an event which will do whatever that trigger was supposed to at certain time intervals? It appears that you have some heavy processing involved there, if you don't need the trigger when update occurs, maybe replace it then?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are going move all triggers to stored procs.